# Customizing the Zendesk pop up box

Tags: zendesk

Where can I edit the CSS of Zendesk's pop-up?

[image]

Inspect found this css but I don't know where the CSS file is located

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These two pages should give you enough information to customize the feedback tab:
https://support.zendesk.com/entries/20990726-Setting-up-your-Feedback-Tab-channel
https://support.zendesk.com/entries/21010623-Customizing-the-Feedback-Tab-with-CSS

You can use the Advanced tab when creating the widget to access the CSS or you can modify the CSS from your page.

You can also edit an existing feedback form if you know the ID by visiting this link:
[yoursite].zendesk.com/account/dropboxes/[feedback_id]/edit